# Socket.IO Emit Object Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, cocos2d-js

am not able to emit object from client to server..
here's the code on my client

```
var foo = {
name: xxx,
type: mytype
};
cc.log(foo);
socket.emit('test', foo);
```

ERROR

```
JS: [object Object]
JSB SocketIO.emit method called
jsb: ERROR: File /Users/xxx/Sites/socketIO/frameworks/js-bindings/bindings/manual/network/jsb_socketio.cpp: Line: 272, Function: js_cocos2dx_SocketIO_emit
Error processing arguments
```

Comment: Do you can emit a string?

Comment: @Joriktos yes i can emit a string..

Comment: Then you have probably a corrupted socket.io client or server or you have an error in your array.
Is console.log( foo ) a valid object?

Comment: What values are in name and type? Strings, arrays or something circular?

Comment: @Joriktos 'jsb: ERROR: File /Users/xxx/Sites/socketIO/frameworks/js-bindings/bindings/manual/cocos2d_specifics.cpp: Line: 5176, Function: js_console_log
js_console_log : Error processing arguments
JS: /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E9344199-9A48-4489-879D-48D8D8BFEB38/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/8388A8F2-C3A6-43B2-A5F3-68C9261524D7/socketIO iOS.app/src/app.js:397:Error: js_console_log : Error processing arguments'

Comment: @EzraMorse anything.. just took strings as an example..

Answer (score 1):

You can't take a javascript object "foo" as the second parameter. As it is defined in SocketIO.h:

```
void emit(std::string eventname, std::string args);
```

The second parameter is a string. Cocos2d-js can't convert a javascript object "foo" to std::string automatically. However, cocos2d-js can convert a javascript string to std::string by jsval_to_std_string().

If you want to send object, you can send object as a string and do decoding on receiving it.